# Is it possible to put a variable in a key() function?

Tags: processing

I am trying to make a calculator in processing. My thought process for how this is going to work is to make a function for if a certain number is pressed on the keyboard. So I would create some sort of for loop or array even that would sense when a number is pressed, and then return true if it goes through the if statements, however, in order for this to work, I would need to put a variable in the place of a specific key on the keyboard. Is this possible?

Code (so far):

```java
void setup() {
  size(800,600);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  Nums.create();
}
class Nums {

  void create() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      zero(i);
    }
  }

  boolean zero(int amnt) {
    if (keyPressed) {
      if (key == amnt) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They `keyPressed` variable and the functions like `keyPressed()` and `keyReleased()` are specifically for keyboard input. They don't, and shouldn't, be concerned with on-screen buttons that you click with the mouse.

Instead, you should probably use the `mousePressed()` function to detect when the mouse is clicked, and then use `if` statements to figure out which button was clicked. You can use point-rectangle [collision detection](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) to detect which button was clicked. There's also a button sketch in the examples that come with the Processing editor.